# String length in a dataframe when they are actually lists or dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    _id      answers                                               options       singleAnswer                                                     
    a       [{'title': 'dog', 'value': True},                     []            [] 
            {'title': 'cat', 'value': False}, 
            {'title': 'bird', 'value': False}]
    b       [{'title': 'food', 'value': False},                   []            [] 
            {'title': 'water', 'value': True}, 
            {'title': 'wine', 'value': False}]
    c       []                                                   [bed,          [sleep]
                                                                 chair,seat]   
    d       []                                                   [[one],[two],  [four]
                                                                 [three]]
```

The reason why they appear as dictionaries is because there was a nested record in BigQuery and I imported it without unnesting it. As for the last two columns, this is what they were like in the initial data set.

Now, **I want to build an extra column that just gives me the total length of the words for each row**. So for the first row I would take `dog`, `cat`, `bird` into consideration and obtain length `10`. For the last row I would take `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` and obtain length `15`.

If there was a simple string, I would just do `df['Length']=df['columnName'].str.len()`, but I can't do that since it gives me the length of the list instead. This is also problematic for the length of dictionary keys, and even more for these weird lists of lists.

Is it possible to take out the string length as it is or should I first convert everything into the strings I am interested in?

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive way would be just to run a function that calculates these lengths using `apply` over your column.

The more performant, and frankly unintuitive, way would be first to explode your `answers` column. Then add to every `dict` an `_id` key corresponding to the source `dict`'s key. (Or otherwise construct a data frame from a series while preserving the original series index after `s.set_index('_id')`.)

After constructing a data frame from the values (`pd.DataFrame(exploded.values)`), get lengths `new_df['title_len'] = new_df['title'].str.len()`, and then in each ID group, sum those lengths: `new_df.groupby('_id')['title_len'].sum()`.

Take your answer and attach it back one-to-one to your original data frame.

Comment: Thank you! So for the last two columns I just made the conversion to string and solved the problem. But for the "answers" columnm I tried: `parsed = df.groupby('_id').answers.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(df.values[0])).reset_index()` and it completely messed it up. It has parsed the cell with "bed, chair, seat" over and over again and it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `df.values[0]` is probably 'bed, chair, seat'